How to access the launch context to perform substitutions for debugging ros2 launch python files?
Many errors in my launch files are a result of substitution failures, but running ros2 launch launch.py -d does not give you substitution values. Accessing the value of a substitution at a runtime seems to requires the use of Substitution.perform(context) (from rolling).
In this minimal launch file from D.Lu's excellent rosetta-launch repo, how do I access the launch context to access the value of the PathJoinSubstitution?
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import PathJoinSubstitution
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterFile
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare


def generate_launch_description():
    file_parameters = ParameterFile(
        param_file=PathJoinSubstitution(FindPackageShare('donatello'), 'config', 'sub_params.yaml'),
        allow_substs=True
    )

return LaunchDescription([
    DeclareLaunchArgument('radius', default_value='1.5'),
    DeclareLaunchArgument('pizza_type', default_value='mushrooms'),
    Node(name='does_machines',
         package='donatello',
         executable='donatello_node',
         parameters=[file_parameters]),
])


The ros2 docs on LaunchContext and OpaqueFunction are pretty poor, but both can be combined to give you all of the info you need from runtime arguments. An example can be found in the UR Robot Driver repository.
In the example below, the required generate_launch_description() returns a LaunchDescription which includes the declared_args and the return of an OpaqueFunction. OpaqueFunctions take a function callback and can also accept additional args and kwargs, like a normal Python function.
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, OpaqueFunction
from launch.substitutions import PathJoinSubstitution
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterFile
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

import rclpy.logging
logger = rclpy.logging.get_logger("donatello.launch")

def launch_setup(context, *args, **kwargs):
    param_file_path_subst = PathJoinSubstitution(FindPackageShare('donatello'), 'config', 'sub_params.yaml')
    param_file_path_str = param_file_path_subst.perform(context=context)
    
    # prints substitution object
    logger.info(param_file_path_subst)
    # prints the absolute path as a string
    logger.info(param_file_path_str)
    
    file_parameters = ParameterFile(
        param_file=param_file_path_subst,
        allow_substs=True
    )
    
    donatello_node = Node(
        name='does_machines',
        package='donatello',
        executable='donatello_node',
        parameters=[file_parameters]
    )
    
    return [file_parameters, donatello_node]
    
def generate_launch_description():
    declared_args = []
    declared_args.append(DeclareLaunchArgument('radius', default_value='1.5')),
    declared_args.append(DeclareLaunchArgument('pizza_type', default_value='mushrooms')),
    
    ld = LaunchDescription(declared_args + [OpaqueFunction(function=launch_setup)])

    return ld

This slightly complicates your launch file but makes debugging far easier.
Alternatively to running a .perform() method on a Substitution object, you can also find the string using the LaunchContext object:
param_file_path_str = context.perform_substitution(param_file_path_subst)

Another tip: do not use launch.actions.LogInfo to log your debugging statements, it's much easier to import rclpy.logging and create a named logger, as demonstrated in the example above.

You need to use launch.actions.OpaqueFunction to perform the substitution. A sample code would be:
def your_opaque_fun(context: launch.LaunchContext, args):
    param_file = PathJoinSubstitution(args) 
    your_substitution = context.perform_substitution(param_file)
    # do something
...

def generate_launch_description():
    ...
    call_opaque_function = OpaqueFunction(function=your_opaque_fun, args=[...])
    ...

    return launch.LaunchDescription([
    ...
    call_opaque_function      
    ])

See also: Can I programmatically call a launch file with arguments that can be used as a variable for python operations
and https://answers.ros.org/question/396345/ros2-launch-file-how-to-convert-launchargument-to-string/. I found these answers particular useful when trying to solve a similar question.
